# Leer Json ionic 3

Tags: jsf, typescript, angular, rest, ionic3

necesito de su ayuda  de como leer o de que manera tratar datos de un JSON(Object) que proviene de un WS de Java. Lo que he hecho es usar [HTTP](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/) de IONIC; el server me responde correctamente.
Mi pregunta es como leer este Object(jSON) en IOnic.

Mi WS retorna un `List<Empleado>`

```
   @GET
    @Path("empleados")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<Empleado> checkTurnos() {
        List<Empleado>emp=daoM.getEmpleadosPlantaMobil();
        return emp;
    }
```

La clase empleado es esta:

```
    private Integer id_empleado;
    private String nombres;
    private String identificacion;
    private String cargo;
    private Integer cod_reloj;
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="empleado", referencedColumnName="id_empleado")
    private List<Timbres> timbres=new ArrayList<>();
     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name = "id_ruta_fabricacion")
    private Ruta_fabricacion ruta_fabricacion;
     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name = "id_turno")
    private Turno turno;
//getters & setters
```

Aquî es donde nose como leer el json

```
   this.http2.get('url',{},{}).then (data => {
    console.log("STADO "+data.status);
    console.log("DATA "+data.data); // datos del servidor
    console.log("HEADERSSS "+data.headers);    

    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
```

Debo decir que el WS esta probado y me retorna algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACTUALIZACION

recorriendo con un for(MI PROBLEMA) como trato estos datos, es decir si quiero sacar los turnos, rutas, etc:

```
for(let k in data.data){
      console.log("> "+k+" "+data.data);
    }
```

En la consola se puede observar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿De qué clase es el atributo http2 de tu componente?

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow si amigo, en el constructor el nombre esta cambiado solo es eso `private http2: HTTP` pero es del mismo tipo

Comment: @JackNavaRow sí itero pero letra por letra lo cual sé que no esta bien!

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow por tomarte un tiempo en ayudarme!! probé con tu código y en la salida me da https://i.imgur.com/A8n8QtX.png.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78795/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-maicoly-guerrero).

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow problema resuelto!

Answer (score 1):

El problema fue que esta recibiendo un String solo necesitaba hacer un `JSON.parse`. Gracias @JackNavaRow!

```
this.empleados=JSON.parse(data.data);
    for(let k in this.empleados){ 
      console.log(this.empleados[k].nombres);
      console.log(this.empleados[k].turno.descripcion);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el for que buscas es:

```
for (let empleado of data.data) {
  console.log("empleado1", empleado);
  console.log("id del empleado1", empleado.id_empleado);
  console.log("id de la ruta de fabricacion", empleado.ruta_fabricacion.id_ruta_fabricacion);
  console.log("id del turno", empleado.turno.id_turno);
}
```

Prueba a ver

Un saludo

PD: Revisa la documentación 
[iterators and generators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) por que tu estás sacando el indice y no el objeto del array

Comment: Hola @Mikel traté tu respuesta pero igual la salida es como que itera una por una es decir letra por letra (caracter)!

Comment: Os referís a sacar la ruta de fabricación? he editado para sacar la id de la ruta de fabricación. No sé, no me queda claro lo que queréis y además, la iteración que habéis puesto, el console log siempre devuelve el array completo. No elemento a elemento

Comment: entiendo como iteras; aunque soy nuevo en ionic muchas gracias!! pero según tu código la consola me arroja este error https://imgur.com/a/l2HzDCs

Comment: no puedo ver el error que me comentas, en el movil veo la imagen ilegible, y desde el pc está bloqueado el acceso. Podría ser que algún registro no tuviera ruta de fabricación o turno?

Comment: Gracias! ya aclare la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta que recibes es un string necesitas parcearlo trata con la instrucción JSON.parse te dejo una liga https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp ademas checa el formato de tu json no lo alcanzo a ver bien pero verifícalo aquí https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ dependiendo como configuraras la respuesta es posible que tengas que pasear mas de una vez.

Comment: Gracias, ya aclare la respuesta!